# Providing a consistent interface for inRange function over modded values

Tags: java, algorithm

I want to write a function named inRange which will have below interface

```
inRange(long a, long b, boolean inclusiveStart, boolean inclusiveEnd)
```

This function calculates if `this.value` is in between `a` & `b`. However there are two important points to note:

1. Two boolean values (inclusiveStart & inclusiveEnd) specify if `a` (or `b`) should be included in the range.
2. All 3 values viz. `a`, `b` and `this.value` are modded values i.e they define a circular range.

I have tried writing this function but here is my concern,

How to provide a consistent interface so that client does not have to worry about circular range. Lets say, `a` == `b` then should the function consider complete range or should it just consider a single value for the range. Or when `a` = 0 & `b` = MOD - 1 then what should be the function behavior for different combinations of boolean values.

Below is my code:

```
private boolean inRangeBothInclusive(long start, long end) {
    if (start == end)
    return this.value == start;
    else if (start < end) {
    return start <= this.value &&
        this.value <= end;
    } else {
    return !(end <= this.value &&
         this.value <= start);
    }
}


public boolean inRange(long start, long end, boolean startInclusive,
               boolean endInclusive) {
    /* Ranges can have bigger start and smaller end value due to mod */

    if (!startInclusive) {
    start = (start + 1) % MOD;
    }
    if (!endInclusive) {
    end = (end - 1) % MOD;
    if (end < 0)
        end += MOD;
    }
    return inRangeBothInclusive(start, end);
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I doubt the boolean values are really necessary unless you want to translate mathematical notation directly. Otherwise I'd prefer exactly one `inRange(long start, long end)` function and clearly communicate in the documentation for the client that the range **always includes** `start` and `end`. Also you completely leave us in darkness, what's the role of `MOD`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: I have written that values are arranged in circular fashion. i.e all values `a` & `b` are Modded using `MOD`

Comment: YAGNI most probably.

Comment: _"i.e all values a & b are Modded using MOD"_ that's another piece of concern, not really related to the _in range_ check. If I'm wrong with my understanding, you'll need to show more code to review. The general rule of thumb is: KISS, don't overcomplicate things.

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to present the boolean parameters in your client API I would do that as follows

```
private boolean inRangeBothInclusive(long start, long end) {
    if (start == end) {
        return this.value == start;
    }
    else if (start < end) {
        return start <= this.value && 
               this.value <= end;
    }
    return !(end <= this.value &&
             this.value <= start);
}
```

---

```
public boolean inRange(long start, long end, boolean startInclusive, boolean endInclusive) {
    start = startInclusive ? start : start + 1;
    end = endInclusive ? end : end - 1;
    return inRangeBothInclusive(start, end);
}
```